# Stencil.js: How to use utils function in index.html

Tags: javascript, typescript, stenciljs

i'm creating a popup stenciljs component.

### File structure:

- popup-element

  - src

    - utils

      - popup-manager
    - components

      - popup-element

        - popup-element.tsx
    - index.html
  - ...

Now i try to insert component to DOM from function:
**popup-manager.ts**

```
export function createMiniNotification(notificationContent: string, mountTarget: HTMLElement = document.body): HTMLElement {
  const notify = document.createElement('popup-element');
  notify.setAttribute('content', notificationContent);
  mountTarget.appendChild(notify);
}
```

How can I use this function in index.html (in development mode)?

Answer (score 4):

**Update:**

You can add exports to `src/index.ts` and then those will be available at `/build/index.esm.js`.

```
// src/index.ts

export const createMiniNotification = (msg: string) => console.log(msg);
```

```html
<script type="module">
  import { createMiniNotification } from '/build/index.esm.js';

  createMiniNotification('Hi');
</script>
```

---

**Original Answer:**

I'd suggest you create a wrapping component, e. g. `app-root` and call your function from there, e. g. in its `componentDidLoad` lifecycle hook:

```js
import { Component, Host, h } from '@stencil/core';
import { createMiniNotification } from '../utils/popup-manager';

@Component({ tag: 'app-root' })
export class AppRoot {
  componentDidLoad() {
    createMiniNotification(/* ... */);
  }

  render() {
    return <Host />;
  }
}
```

Then you can just add this wrapper component in your `index.html`:

```html
<app-root></app-root>
```

Comment: This should be marked as the answer. I tried it and it works perfectly.